# Selenium, EdgeDriver Version 116.0.1983.54 - WindowHandles not increased when print dialog was opened

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

We are testing a WebApp with Selenium 4 on Edge browser.

Today the Browser was updated to Microsoft Edge for Business Version 116.0.1938.54 in our company, and thus we also had to update the Webdriver to version 116.0.1938.54

We are facing the following issue now in our TestAutomation project: We use the count of WindowHandles to check if a PrintDialog was opened. So far (until Edge/WebDriver Version 115) the WindowHandles was increased by 1 when the PrintDialog was opened and we could switch to it an close it.
Since the update we are facing the issue that the count of WindowHandles remains unchanged when the Print Dialog is opened (even though the Print Dialog was opened successfully)

Anybody else facing this issues? Does any know a workaround for this?

We were expecting the behaviour to be unchanged in Edge and WebDriver Version 116.
So far I could not find any information that this was changed intentionally.

We also updated Selenium to the latest Version 4.11 but didn't change anything :(

Screenshot:
[Count of WindowHandles remains 1 event though PrintDialog is open - was 2 before usind Edge + EdgeDriver Version 115](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y98hn.png)

**Update 4.9.2023**

Today I found out that if I add "webview" to the WindowTypes during creation of the driver by calling AddWindowTypes("webview") on the EdgeOptions the WindowHandles are increased to 2 again after print ist triggered.
Unfortunately this does not solve my issue.
It looks like now with this second window I only have access to the right part of the print dialog where the preview of the document is shown :(  I still found no way to click the "Cancel" Button

Comment: Can you confirm visually that indeed the window handles look correct and you can see the print dialog by pausing the test at that point or having it take a screenshot?

Comment: I edited the description and attachted a Screenshot.
The problem indeed ist that in my opinion the window handels are NOT correct. I would have expected to have 2 window handles (as it was before the update to the new Edge and EdgeDriver version)

Comment: According to your description, this problem only occurs after updating to version 116 in Microsoft Edge. In this case, you can press `Alt+Shift+I` to edit this issue and report to relevant team. In addition, if possible, you can also try rolling back Edge to version 115 to see if it still works correctly.

Comment: @XudongPeng I guess you mean I should mean I should press Alt+Shift+I in the Edge Browser to report an issue there, right?
Downgrading to Edge Version 115 is not an option unfortunately, as it's decided by the company which software is installed in which version on the machines :(

Comment: Today I found out that if I add "webview" to the WindowTypes during creation of the driver by calling AddWindowTypes("webview") on the EdgeOptions the WindowHandles are increased to 2 again after print ist triggered. 
Unfortunately this does not solve my issue. 
It looks like now with this second window I only have access to the right part of the print dialog where the preview of the document is shown :(  I still found no way to click the "Cancel" Button 
I added this Info also in the description above

Comment: Yes, if this issue occurs only after updating to version 116, you can report this issue to the relevant team. You can also try testing in the canary version to see if the problem still exists, if it is fixed then you can wait for its update.

Comment: @AnitaBogner: Facing same issue. Not working in edge version 117 as well.

Comment: @AnitaBogner: Same code works fine with Chrome browser version 117.0.5938.92 and with same ChromeDriver version. But not working with Edge browser and edgedriver versions of 117.0.2045.36! Please let me know if you get some update on this.

Comment: @AnitaBogner: Still not working with MS Edge and msedgedriver both in latest version 118. Did you get any other solution for this?

Comment: @harsha.cs I also tried it yesterday with Edge /WebDriver 118. As you said unfortunately still not working :( I also did not find a solution or workaround so far. Sorry